# Running a .NET core application using PM2

Tags: pm2, asp.net-core-5.0

If I run my .NET core 5 webAPI console app via the exe file, it's listening to all interfaces just as I configured in my appsettings.json

If I run it via pm2, it's accessible only from 127.0.0.1 even though my app logs show it listening to all interfaces.

Why?

Comment: Made some progress. This seems to be related to the SSL certificate my service is using.
When I used the development certificate installed by dotnet, when running my service via pm2, it didn't recognize it and didn't listen on the https port I configured for my app.

So I created a normal self-signed certificate, and now it does listen but something is closing the connection when I try to access from a browser. Unless I run my app outside of pm2 in which case it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certificate I used was exported from IIS into a pfx file with a password and then imported into the Windows certificates store.
For some reason pm2 didn't like that certificate.

When created a new certificate using Openssl into 2 pem files and used that for my .NET core project, pm2 gave me no problems.